# Microsoft.Graph API+Sharepoint - CreateLink which blocks download and grant access to external users

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I am having a difficult time creating a sharing link with Microsoft.Graph API that is blocking downloads and share the link with external pears.

I managed to create a link which is blocking users from downloading the shared files, however, whenever I try to grant access to this link to external pears I am getting an exception telling me that "One or more users could not be resolved".

Has anybody got a hint for me what I may be doing wrong?

My code is

```
            Permission linkresult = driveItemRequestBuilder.CreateLink("blocksDownload", "users", null, null, null).Request().PostAsync().Result;

            string base64Value = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(linkresult.Link.WebUrl));
            string encodedUrl = "u!" + base64Value.TrimEnd('=').Replace('/', '_').Replace('+', '-');
```

So far this seems to work but once I want to grant access to the link with this code

```
                IPermissionGrantCollectionPage grantedPermissions = this.GraphClient.Shares[encodedUrl].Permission.Grant(roles, recipients).Request().PostAsync().Result;
```

I am getting the exception:

> Code: invalidRequest
> Message: One or more users could not be resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used to met the similar issue when sharing files to external users using graph api.
Finally resolved it by enabling external sharing in admin center.

Please make sure that the exteranl settings is set to Anyone both in [organization-level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/turn-external-sharing-on-or-off) and [site-level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/change-external-sharing-site).

[image]

Comment: Hi Michael,

Thank you very much for the quick reply, I'll get in touch with our sharepoint admin to check this...

Kind regards

Sebastian